# Does This Contain Encryption?

Tags: iphone, encryption

I'm kind of confused about what encryption is within an iPhone app... This is part of one of my apps and I wanted to make sure it doesn't contain encryption. Could someone help me out with this?

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
}

#pragma mark - Twitter Interactions
-(void)getTweet
{
    // Specify the URL and parameters
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=youdabrogames&include_rts=1"];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"count", nil];
    // Create the TweetRequest object
    TWRequest *tweetRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:parameters requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
    [tweetRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        // Request completed and we have data
        // Output it!
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        id timelineData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
        if(timelineData == NULL) {
            // There was an error changing the data to a Foundation Object,
            // so we'll output a bunch of debug information.
            NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"\n\nConversion to object failed.");
            NSLog(@"HTTP Response code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
            NSLog(@"Output from server: %@", myString);
            NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@\n\n", [jsonError localizedDescription]);
            abort();
            // TODO: Show a graceful error message here
        }
        NSDictionary *timelineDict = (NSDictionary*) timelineData;
        NSLog(@"\n\nConversion succeeded!");
        NSLog(@"%@\n\n", timelineDict);
        tweetLabel.text = @"";
        tweetLabel.text = [[(NSArray*)timelineDict objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"text"];
    }];
}
```

Comment: @rckoenes: how can you edited in 7 sec?. Please provide me guild line..:)

Comment: i can't see any encryption in your posted code

Comment: @Nit 53 seconds, and 7 seconds isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I see [JSON](http://www.json.org/); I don't see encryption at this level.